# Can I ask many questions about shape sequences? Then how can I give title to them?

Tags: discussion

There are some shape sequences for which I can't find an answer or the reason for the given answer. Can I ask them? However, then I don't know what title to use for each cause they are all like "What is next in this sequence"

Answer (score 3):

## *Can* you? Yes. *Should* you? Probably not.

"What is the next in this sequence" patterns are often poorly-received. If you do decide to ask a lot of these, you will likely be heavily downvoted. (Also, keep this in mind: If you're getting these from somewhere else, you *must* have permission, and you must say *where* they come from.)

Enjoyable puzzles naturally lead to unique titles, based on the aspect of the puzzle that *makes* it enjoyable - the part that makes it interesting. If you can't think of a unique title to give your puzzle, that is a clear sign that the puzzle is boring.  It won't be fun for people to solve, and it likely won't get a good reception.

Comment: OP has [indicated](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60608/what-is-the-next-in-this-sequence-of-tables#comment185285_60608) that they're from a past entrance exam for an Iranian university. Should be fine for him to post them, but like you said, he needs to state where they're from (and not spam them at a rapid rate).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your actual question ...

### Yes, these puzzles are on-topic.

As Deusovi says, it's not advisable to post loads of them in quick succession - they won't get closed, but they'll likely get a lot of downvotes if you do that. People will soon get bored of a long sequence of similar-looking puzzles, even if each one on its own is perfectly valid. But that's the point: each one is perfectly valid. **As long as there is a unique and verifiable solution** (as there should be to any puzzle), asking for the next in a sequence of images is an OK puzzle and possibly even a good one. Just don't go over the top with them and you should be fine.

### Title them as distinctively as you can.

Every question should *try* to have a distinctive title, so that you can tell roughly what it's about just from a quick glance at the title. We don't always succeed in doing this - it's been a problem for a long time here on Puzzling; see [Non-descriptive titles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1445/5373), [Informative titles for rebus puzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2807/5373), [Titling Overhaul](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1438/5373), etc. - but we should at least *try*. I've made a LOT of edits over the years to give puzzles more descriptive titles than things like "What am I riddle" or "Another rebus puzzle".

How to do this will depend on the nature of the puzzle; I can't really give you much generic advice. If you're asking about a sequence of letters or numbers or words, put at least some of the sequence into the title. If you're asking about a sequence of images, maybe at least try to *describe* the images in the title? "What's the next in this sequence of [boxes filled with black and white balls](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/60725/5373)", for instance.